# How can I get an array of certain key-values?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

```
var obj = [
  {
    "amount": " 12185",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "amount": "147421",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "MAY",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "amount": "2347",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "AUGUST",
    "year": "2010"
  }
]
```

How can i get all amounts, that is `'12185'`, `'147421'`, `'2347'`.
I've tried to do this

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])
```

Comment: `obj` is not an object, it's an array of objects. (Name it correctly and) use the right tools for it (`Array.prototype.map()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "amount": " 12185",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "amount": "147421",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "MAY",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "amount": "2347",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "AUGUST",
    "year": "2010"
  }
];

let amounts = obj.map(v => v.amount);
console.log(amounts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `obj` variable is actually an array. (denoted by the braces `[]`)

You can use the map function on an array to return what you're asking for.

```
var amounts = obj.map(x => x.amount); // Array(3) [ " 12185", "147421", "2347" ]
```

You may also want to append .trim() to the end of x.amount to remove any spaces specifically.

```
var amounts = obj.map(x => x.amount.trim()); // Array(3) [ "12185", "147421", "2347" ]
```

```
var obj = [
  {
    "amount": " 12185",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "amount": "147421",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "MAY",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "amount": "2347",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "AUGUST",
    "year": "2010"
  }
];


var amounts = obj.map(x => x.amount);

console.log(keys); // Array(3) [ " 12185", "147421", "2347" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `obj` is an array, you'll need:

```js
const vals = obj.map(entry => entry.amount); // ["12185", "147421", "2347"]
```